# LDAP Redirect from consumer if producer is online

Tags: ldap, producer-consumer

I got LDAP server with posix users set up, they can login using LDAP etc, but now I came across serious problem... hope it's real to implement.
I need to implement mechanism like this:
When someone logs in or tries to change the password consumer LDAP usually should redirect to producer, but if producer is offline then consumer user DB should be used, and there's no way to change password at all. How do i make it?

Maybe there's any producer on\off based switches etc.?